# JSON API Wordpress not showing featured image when uploaded via App

Tags: json, wordpress

I am facing some unknown issues with wordpress featured image. When I update a featured image from the website; it gets displayed in the app via json.

http://indiafastener.com/api/?json=get_post&post_type=listing-item&id=1377

however when I upload an image via json into the wordpress db; the output is NULL in the image field.

http://indiafastener.com/api/?json=get_post&post_type=listing-item&id=1380

when I see the db; it has the image path and the path does not lead to 404.

**Image Path:**
http://www.indiafastener.com/webservices/listing/uploads/2017-04-01_12-01-40IMG-20150715-WA0004.jpg

Could it be because the image is not there in the `wp-content/uploads/2016/02/` folder?

**Code to upload the image**

```
require_once('../../wp-config.php');
require_once('../../wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$dirname = "../../wp-content/uploads/2017/01/";
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg',
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'guid' => $dirname.basename($filename)
//'wp-content/uploads/2017/01/' . basename($filename)
);
$your_post_id  = 1392;
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename,'$your_post_id' );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
//$id=1385;
update_post_meta($id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
echo "success";
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

**Screenshots**

DB post_type attachment of image uploaded via app
[image]

DB Post linked to the image Id
[image]

Missing Image Preview:
[image]

Comment: In the screenshot of the missing image preview, can you paste in a comment what the full url is of that image?  You can also take a look at this post, it might help solve your problem: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231137/wp-rest-api-how-to-get-featured-image

Comment: http://www.indiafastener.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/2017-10-01_12-01-04IMG-20150715-WA0004.jpg

Here is the path of the image. Thanks I'll check that plugin as well..

Comment: Did you check the permissions of the image in the image directory?   Sometimes they get uploaded (when done manually) with different permissions than when done through the wordpress media library.

Comment: can you update your post with how do you send picture via api?

Comment: thanks for the help guys the issue was that i was passing relative url and not absolute url while saving the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about your code but my below piece of code is working perfectly for assign image as feature image for post. please go through it.
attachment id should be assign to particulate post, check your post meta '_thumbnail_id' for post as well.

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

$filename = 'your file name';

$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => 'your mime type',
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($filename)
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename,'your_post_id' );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
update_post_meta($id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
```