# upload PNG using set_post_thumbnail in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

It works fine for JPG but for PNG.

I wonder which part am I gonna change to make this work for PNG as well.

Here is my code

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

$pid = wp_insert_post( $my_post ); //retrieves the last inserted post id

$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'my_image_upload', $pid );

if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {

    $mine_msg = "There was an error uploading the image.";

} else {

    $mine_msg = "The image was uploaded successfully!";

    set_post_thumbnail( $pid , $attachment_id );

}
```

Please suggest me if this question needs to be changed or removed, instead of voting down my question.

Thanks :)

Comment: any error you are getting when you try to upload png ?

Comment: no error.. posts with PNG gets published same as posts with JPG. But PNG's are not getting uploaded.

Comment: try to check " image.php " , " file.php " , and " media.php" i guess somewhere there must be array written for the allowed extensions.

Comment: check this post and if possible try code from it....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501230/json-api-wordpress-not-showing-featured-image-when-uploaded-via-app/41610085#41610085

Comment: @PunitGajjar Thanks a lot

Comment: @AshPatel it seems to work for some users. Really weird.

Comment: I came to know that the users who couldn't upload PNGs have viruses in their PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution. Posting here for future reference.

After trying the comments/suggestions by Punit Gajjar and Ash Patel for hours I came to know that it was a virus in my client's desktop. The virus prevented him from uploading images.

Both mine and Ash Patel's code (link in comment above) works.